# OS X Mavericks seems to be corrupting my sleep image

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake

I've been running Mavericks and there seems to be some issue with sleeping.  If I run the battery down to zero, the laptop automatically hibernates as usual.  When I turn the laptop on, it boots, then immediately restarts - losing the sleep data in the process.

There don't seem to be any other issues, no kernel panics or anything like that.  Indeed there are no error messages of any kind, save for the obvious fact that it's just done a normal reboot.  Most applications deal with it gracefully, opening as if they crashed, but services like Python close and if the program doesn't handle it properly, data gets lost.

I'm wondering if it's a battery issue?  I had issues with an old battery (since replaced) where OS X would just die at low battery instead of hibernating, but even then it didn't reboot after turning on.  However, this has only started since I upgrade.

Any suggestions?

I have a mid 2009 13" Macbook, OS X 10.9, 4GB RAM and a 256GB Crucial M4 SSD.

Comment: After a strange restart while battery charging I set hibernate mode from '3' by default to '25' and closed lid. Laptop hibernates and when I turn it on, system wakes up from hibernate normally. Hmm, so thats questions: - I have FileVault turned on. Maybe this is problem while hibernate mode is '3'?
- system wakes up with hibernate mode '25' normally while battery charging. Would this OK if battery down to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you aren't running any 3rd party utilities or have previously changed your hibernation settings here is what I would do:

1. run `sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 3`
2. Verify your disk using disk utility. repair any problems.
3. delete the sleep image `sudo rm /private/var/vm/sleepimage`

if that doesn't fix it try an [SMC reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964)

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a different issue.  Turns out that a number of services were locking OS X's ability to sleep - the main culprit seemed to be Internet Sharing being enabled accidentally.

I had a look at:

```
pmset -g assertions
```

And tracked down the processes that were listed.  When the battery got low, these overrode everything and the laptop turned off instead of hiberinating.